Maximo Control Desk (7) SSO with Microsoft Entra
I am currently working on integrating Maximo Control Desk with Microsoft Entra to configure Single Sign-On (SSO). I have been following a manual I found referenced in another post, but I am encountering difficulties. When i navigate to this ACS URL, i receive the error "INTERNAL ERROR: Please contact your support."
Has anyone successfully completed this integration? If so, could you please share the steps or any additional insights that might help me resolve this issue?
I tried following the IBM documentation (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/control-desk/7.6.1.x?topic=security-configuring-assertion-markup-language-saml) about the properties, but I still get the error.
